# The VS code gets fake errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I write code with Visual Studio code, but after changed my computer Windows the VSCode takes fake error like this:

```
message: 'Property 'splice' does not exist on type '{}'.'
```

Here is my code:

```
storedImages = [];
removeImageAtIndex(index: number) {
    this.storedImages.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

And it gets other fake errors, I know that my code doesn't have any error because my project before changed my computer windows work correctly, but now gets fake errors a lot. I think that the problem is of VScode,

Visual Studio code property:

```
Version 1.19.2
Commit 490ef761b76b3f3b3832eff7a588aac891e5fe80
Date 2018-01-10T15:55:03.538Z
Shell 1.7.9
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64

npm version: 6.4.1
node version: v10.15.3
java version: 1.7.0_80
javac version: 1.8.0_231
```

And this is an Ionic project, please help me thanks.

Comment: I think it should be `this.storedImages = []`

Comment: storedImages  and this.storedImages   may be different values, 
`this` is used to   referring to Object context and  
currently the context is not clear from the code your provided.


`
storedImages = ['abcddd'];
removeImageAtIndex(index: number) {
    console.log( this.storedImages) // please check this value 
    this.storedImages.splice(index, 1);
  }
`